# SQL Server service gives error after enabling TLS 1.2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tls1.2

I have recently updated my Web Server "Windows Server 2008 R2" with TLS 1.2. I also changed settings on SQL Server machine to have TLS 1.2 enabled. Since then I am getting below error when I try to run my application.

> Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) on Local
>   Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this
>   is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to
>   service-specific error code 5023.

So far I have tried to run below two KBs from Microsoft. But none of them is applicable to my SQL Server version.

SQLServer2012-KB3194719-x64
SQLServer2012-KB4025925-x64

My SQL Server's internal version is 11.0.2100.60

Comment: Have you reviewed the error log, and if so, what does that say?

Comment: It says a fatal error occurred related to SSL

Comment: To re-verify, I reverted the TLS 1.2 settings by enabling TLS 1.0, 1.1 and SSL 3.0 on my SQL Server. Now the website throws this error



Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm]

Comment: You tagged SQL Server 2008 R2, but your SQL Server version is SQL Server 2012 (without service packs). Reference: [SQL Server versions](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). If you indeed are running 2012, did you try installing the service packs?

Comment: Yes. Now I am trying to install SP4 on the server. 2008 version was tagged mistakenly. I will correct it. Thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: That error isn't related to TLS1.2. It says that the *service* itself can't start. TLS1.2 affects how clients connect to the service. What does the Event Log show? BTW why would the *application* try to start the service? SQL Server is a service that typically starts as soon as the server itself starts. Did you try using a User Instance database with SQL Server Express perhaps?

Comment: It was found that the SQL Server installation is corrupted somehow. Now trying yo re-install after reverting the TLS settings back to 1.0 and 1.1